# Showing a particular value in combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

It looks like a simple problem but I'm stuck completely - here is the problem:

I have a combobox `cmbConstriant`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_link.ConstraintLayerLinkType))
{
    BindingList<MyConstraintObj> allConstraints = GetAllConstraintLinks(m_project.NetworkLayers);
    cmbConstriant.DataSource = allConstraints;
    cmbConstriant.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cmbConstriant.SelectedText=m_link.ConstraintLayerLinkType;  
}
else
{
    BindingList<MyConstraintObj> allConstraints = GetAllConstraintLinks(m_project.NetworkLayers);
    cmbConstriant.DataSource = allConstraints;
    cmbConstriant.DisplayMember = "Value";
}
```

The values are binding properly but when `m_link.ConstraintLayerLinkType` is empty.

when it has some string it should show that value and other values should be there in drop down. basically `m_link.ConstraintLayerLinkType` is user selected value from the dropdown.

It is showing same result for both the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cmbConstriant.SelectedIndex = cmbConstriant.Items.IndexOf(m_link.ContraintLayerLinkType);
```

Edit:

I see you're adding Items of the class `MyConstraintObj` to the Combo. In `MyConstraintObj`  class add this -

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    String sCompareString = obj as String;
    if (sCompareString == null) return false;
    return ConstraintLayerLinkType == sCompareString;
}
```

IndexOf function compares the item you're passing (string) with every other item in the combobox, but since they are of type `MyConstraintObj`, it is comparing them incorrectly, this function will force comparison of only the variable `ConstraintLayerLinkType` with any string value you pass.

Comment: cmbConstriant.Items.IndexOf(m_link.ContraintLayerLinkType) is giving value -1 even though Item list has m_link.ContraintLayerLinkType

Comment: I got this but when we call IndexOf any item equal method is called internally ?

Comment: Yes IndexOf compares each combobox item with the value you pass, And if the ComboBox item is a custom class, you have to implement Equals method..